# Complex data ordering in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume that I have the following MySQL Table (assume that table name is `'t'`:

```
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
|  ID | Movie                        | Rating | Purchased  |
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
|  1  | Big Adventure                | G      | 2002-03-06 |
|  2  | Shiny Things, The            | PG     | 2002-03-06 |
|  3  | End of the Line              | R      | 2001-02-05 |
|  4  | A Rat named Darcy            | G      | 2003-04-19 |
|  5  | Head First Rules             | R      | 2003-04-19 |
|  6  | Mad Clowns                   | R      | 1999-11-20 |
|  7  | Greg: The Untold Story       | PG     | 2001-02-05 |
|  8  | Potentially Habitable Planet | PG     | 2001-02-05 |
|  9  | Weird Things from Space      | PG     | 2003-04-19 |
| 10  | Shark Bait                   | G      | 1999-11-20 |
| 11  | Take it Back                 | R      | 2001-02-05 |
| 12  | The White Mare               | PG     | 2006-08-15 |
| 13  | Simuduck Exposed             | PG     | 2001-05-06 |
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
```

What I would like to do is get the items from the table and satisfying the following conditions:

1. Order by rating in ascending order and date in descending order
2. Display the first from the each rating, followed by the second item of each rating, and so on.
3. If one of the ratings is 'exhausted', then move on to the other two ratings, and so on, until all items are displayed

If this seems confusing to you, do not worry, it is. To explain it better, here are the results I like from the table above:

```
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
|  ID | Movie                        | Rating | Purchased  |
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
|  4  | A Rat named Darcy            | G      | 2003-04-19 |
| 12  | The White Mare               | PG     | 2006-08-15 |
|  5  | Head First Rules             | R      | 2003-04-19 |
|  1  | Big Adventure                | G      | 2002-03-06 |
|  9  | Weird Things from Space      | PG     | 2003-04-19 |
| 11  | Take it Back                 | R      | 2001-02-05 |
| 10  | Shark Bait                   | G      | 1999-11-20 |
|  2  | Shiny Things, The            | PG     | 2002-03-06 |
|  3  | End of the Line              | R      | 2001-02-05 |
| 13  | Simuduck Exposed             | PG     | 2001-05-06 |
|  6  | Mad Clowns                   | R      | 1999-11-20 |
|  7  | Greg: The Untold Story       | PG     | 2001-02-05 |
|  8  | Potentially Habitable Planet | PG     | 2001-02-05 |
|-----|------------------------------|--------|------------|
```

If you examine the results table above, you notice the following:

1. The **first** movie picked is "A Rat named Darcy". This movie is selected because

   a) it is the **first** of the the G rating movies (ratings are ordered in ascending order)

   b) and with the **highest date** in the G rating movies (dates are ordered in descending order)
2. The **second** movie picked is "The White Mare". This movie is selected because

   a) it is the **first** of the the PG rating movies (ratings are ordered in ascending order)

   b) and with the **highest date** in the PG ratings movies (dates are ordered in descending order)
3. The **third** movie picked is "Head First Rules". This movie is selected because

   a) it is the **first** of the the R rating movies (ratings are ordered in ascending order)

   b) and with the **highest date** in the R rating movies (dates are ordered in descending order)
4. The **fourth** movie picked is "Big Adventure". This movie is selected because

   a) it is the **second** of the the G rating movies (ratings are ordered in ascending order)

   b) and with the **second highest date** in the G rating movies (dates are ordered in descending order)
5. The **fifth** movie picked is "Weird Things from Space". This movie is selected because

   a) it is the **second** of the the PG rating movies (ratings are ordered in ascending order)

   b) and with the **second highest date** in the PG rating movies (dates are ordered in descending order)

And so on. I hope you figured out the pattern by now.

So, my question is, is there a way of doing that in one sql statement? If not, or if the solution is performance intensive, what are your suggestions of a solution that includes a mysql and a programming language solution (php)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well now I need to know the real world case where someone would want such a nonsensical sort order...

Comment: If this was for Oracle or SQL Server, we could make use of "analytic functions" like ROW_NUMBER() .Unfortunately, the types of analytic functions we would need aren't available in MySQL. But in MySQL, we can emulate some of the them with some clever, careful usage of user-defined variables.

Comment: @karina - This is a business case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enumerating the values for each rating and then doing an `order by` in an outer query:

```
select ID, Movie, Rating, Purchased 
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@r = rating, @rn + 1,
                        if(@r := rating, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @r := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by rating, Purchased desc
     ) r
order by rn, rating;
```

Comment: Unfortunately did't work. I have to dissect your suggestion and trace back, to try to get it to work.

Comment: @Greeso . . . Probably because the dates were ordered backwards.

Comment: It looks like the value from rating column is being assigned to `@rn`, I think that is supposed to be assigned to `@r`.

Comment: Since both solutions work, I will not choose either as the accepted solution, it is just not fair to the other person

Comment: Just curious, how is this going to perform in large table situations?

Comment: @Greeso . . . That depends on the time to sort the data.  An index on `t(rating, purchased)` would normally help.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of MySQL user-defined variables.

Note that the MySQL Reference Manual warns that the behavior of user-defined variables used in this way is *undefined*. (This statement depends on a specific order of operations performed by MySQL which is not guaranteed.)

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.movie
      , r.rating
      , r.purchased 
   FROM ( -- 
          SELECT @rownum := IF(t.rating = @rating, @rownum + 1, 1) AS seq
               , t.id
               , t.movie
               , @rating := t.rating AS rating
               , t.purchased
            FROM ( SELECT @rating := NULL, @rownum := 0) i
           CROSS
            JOIN t t 
           ORDER BY t.rating ASC, t.purchased DESC
        ) r
  ORDER BY r.seq ASC, r.rating ASC
```

The inline view i initializes user-defined variables, so the statement execution won't be influenced by the values that are currently in the variables.

The inline view r sorts the rows in the specified sequences, and then compares the current row to values from the previous row, to determine whether @rownum should be incremented by 1 (when the rating is the same as the previous), or reset to 1, when a new rating is encountered.

The value of the rating column from the current row is "saved" into the user-defined variable @rating, so it can be compared to the value of the rating column on the next row (when the next row is processed.)

For each row, the value assigned to @rownum is returned in the column named seq.

The outer query reorders the set, based on the seq column  first (the rownum value that was assigned), and then the rating.

Comment: This works like a charm. I did not delve into the details yet on how this works, but it works perfectly. I thank you for your input. I have one question though, assuming this is a super large table, is the solution performance-intensive?

Comment: Since both solutions work, I will not choose either as the accepted solution, it is just not fair to the other person